# Twilio Push Notifications: Get received status when sending using Passthrough API

Tags: push-notification, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using the Twilio Notify Service to send push notifications to APN and FCM. We would like to switch to the passthrough API for situations where we send to a large number of users at once. Howerver, I'm not getting the `to_binding` field in the response, so have no idea how many succeeded or failed. When sending using `identity`, we get an array of identities.

Here is what we are sending:

```
twilio_client.notify.v1.services(ENV.fetch('TWILIO_NOTIFY_SERVICE')).notifications.create(
  to_binding: params[:users],
  body: params[:body],
  title: params[:title],
  data: {data: @data},
  fcm: {
    data: {
      title: params[:title],
      body: params[:body]
    }
  }
)
```

I get notifications on the devices, but this is what I get back:

```
{"body": "stuff", "sound": null, "sms": null, "alexa": null, "facebook_messenger": null, "tags": [], "title": "My Title", "segments": [], "ttl": 545435, "gcm": null, "account_sid": "account_id", "priority": "high", "apn": null, "data": {"data": {"a_thing": 995, "type": "My Type", "id": 4344}}, "sid": "myid", "action": null, "date_created": "2019-11-05T15:25:27Z", "service_sid": "service_id", "identities": [], "fcm": {"data": {"body": "stuff", "title": "My Title"}}}
```

in the example from the docs (https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource?code-sample=code-send-a-notification-to-bindings-in-the-request-1&code-language=Ruby&code-sdk-version=5.x), it looks like a `toBindings` field should come back.

Is there a way to get this working, or some way to fetch received receipt data after with the notification id?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as of now, this feature is not implemented, and is mentioned in their coming soon section along with iOS/Android SDKs